# Upgrading from Facebook Sdk 2.0 to 3.+ Android - Session invalid

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to update an old code using Facebook 2.0 SDK.
As stated in the upgrade guide https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading
I am creating a new session from a valid saved access token using:

```
AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.createFromExistingAccessToken(
                    access_token,
                    new Date(getExpiration), null, null, Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.facebook_permissions)));

            session.open(accessToken, new Session.StatusCallback() {
                @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                    Session.setActiveSession(session);
                }
            });
```

The session then is then opened with state:
{Session state:OPENED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[email, user_birthday, user_checkins, user_hometown, user_location, publish_stream, publish_checkins, friends_location, friends_hometown, friends_work_history, friends_education_history]}, appId:@@@@}

But now every time I do any request (Graph, HTTP) using this session, It will CLOSE and I will receive a 400 error:

{Response:  responseCode: 400, graphObject: null, error: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 190, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: Error validating access token: Session does not match current stored session. This may be because the user changed the password since the time the session was created or Facebook has changed the session for security reasons.}, isFromCache:false}

Again the token is valid and tested on the web's debug page.